# How did "chiave" get a masculine ending?

Tags: etymology, gender, spelling

As far as I can tell, the descendants of Latin "[clavis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clavis#Latin)" are all feminine, but in Italian "[chiave](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chiave#Italian)", although it is also feminine, on the surface appears to be masculine: chiave/chiavi.

How did this feminine word get a typically masculine ending?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Italian names usually stem from the accusative, in this case “clavem”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, nouns ending in **-o** are masculine (*il gelato, il tavolo*) and those ending in **-a** are feminine (*l’arancia, la sedia*).

Nouns ending in **-e** can be either masculine or feminine (*il cellulare* is masculine, *la chiave* is feminine).

A few nouns ending in **-a** are masculine (*il cinema, il problema*) and a few ending in **-o** are feminine (*la foto, la mano*).

Masculine nouns, in the plural, normally end in **-i**.

Feminine nouns ending in **-a** end in **-e** in the plural, while feminine nouns ending in **-e** end in **-i** in the plural.

Words ending **–ore** are usually masculine

- l'onore (the honor)
- il fiore (the flower)
- il professore (the professor)

Words ending **–ione** are usually feminine

- una prenotazione (a reservation)
- un’escursione (an excursion)
- una destinazione (a destination)
- una stazione (a station)

With human beings the gender of the noun is usually determined by the sex of the person referred to

- il cantante / la cantante (the singer)
- il paziente / la paziente (the patient)
- il consorte / la consorte (the spouse)

Most masculine nouns ending in **-tore** change to **-trice** for the feminine

- l'attore → l'attrice (the actor)
- il traditore → la traditrice (the traitor)

Exceptions include: tintore → tintora (dyer) / avventore → avventora (customer) / impostore → impostora (imposter)

So we have that **most of the nouns** agree with the following rules:

- Masculine nouns end with **–o** for singular, **-i** for plural.
- Feminine nouns end with **–a** for singular, **-e** for plural.
- A third category of nouns end with **–e** for singular, **-i** for plural; they can be masculine or feminine, according to the vocabulary.

[image]

Within the first two classes, some nouns form the plural based on specific rules.

[image]
[image]

[Source of the tables: online Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/plurale-dei-nomi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)

Comment: Where do those tables come from? May we reproduce them here?

Comment: @DaG from [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/plurale-dei-nomi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)

Comment: If a word is masculine "-a", the plural is still "-i"? dilemma/dilemmi? You mean "nouns" not "names". In French, "nom" is both "name" and "noun", so I imagine it's the same in Italian.

Comment: @CJDennis sure! It was a typo.

Comment: @alexjo It was a [thinko](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thinko)!

Comment: This reply doesn’t actually answer the question.

Comment: @Tom S. Fox why not?

Answer (score 4):

-*e* is not a typically masculine ending at all. Just think of *ape*, *arte*, *automobile*, *base*, *botte*, *capitale*, *carne*, *cassaforte*, *cenere*, *classe*, *comune*, *croce*, *estate*, *falce*, *fame*, *fede*, *filiale*, *fine*, *frase*, *gente*, *igiene*, *indole*, *lavastoviglie*, *legge*, *lepre*, *lince*, *luce*, *madre*, *mente*, *moglie*, *morale*, *nave*, *neve*, *noce*, *note*, *notte*, *pace*, *parete*, *patente*, *percentuale*, *polvere*, *pulce*, *quiete*, *reclame*, *rete*, *selce*, *serpe*, *sete*, *spirale*, *stampante*, *tigre*, *torre*, *trave*, *visuale*, *voce*, *volpe*, all nouns ending in -*ie*, most nouns ending in -*ice*, -*igine*, -*ione*, -*ite*, -*udine*, etc.

Comment: I'm currently learning Italian, and if I don't know the gender of a noun, guessing masculine for "-e"/"-i" gets it right much more often than not. I'm aware there will always be exceptions as my French is quite good, and 5 out of 6 French "-e" nouns are feminine. I am aware of the difference between a rule of thumb and an absolute rule. Are you saying that the majority of Italian "-e" nouns aren't masculine?

Comment: I have no idea what the exact gender proportions of Italian nouns ending in -_e_ are, but I could compile an interminable list of those that are feminine if you want me to.

Comment: I have found this site: https://www.italki.com/article/470/The-Guide-To-Gender-In-Italian. While I haven't counted them all, it appears that the ratio of masculine to feminine is 2:1.

Comment: I hardly think the nouns listed on that web page are representative of the entire language, and even if we assume that the ratio _is_ 2:1, calling -*e* a masculine ending would still be incorrect. At any rate, I would say your question has been answered.

Comment: @CJDennis The *-e/-i* endings in Italian are a reflex of the third declension in Latin, which contained masculine, feminine and neuter nouns. It is *not* a masculine ending and it is not perceived as such by native speakers.

Comment: @DenisNardin Care to make that an answer?

Comment: @CJDennis The site you mention is not trying to convey the idea that the *-e* ending is mostly masculine. It just gives some rough criteria for deciding on the gender, but it is also warning that it's not possible to have a definite rule.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. It's like responding to the statement "Most animals are insects" by saying, no, elephant, cat, dog, gopher, bat, horse, ox, goat, mouse, badger, monkey, aardvark, koala, possum, bear, dear, mongoose, leopard, rabbit, hamster, kangaroo, dingo, tiger, lion, wolf, antelope, platypus, echidna, wombat, numbat, wallaby, quoll, rat, rhinoceros, hippopotamus, giraffe, pig, moose, squirrel, cow, sheep, gorilla, sloth, lemur, etc.

Comment: Sorry, @CJDennis, but your comment is a bit funny, coming from the author of a “terrible” question with a made-up rule about a “typically masculine ending”. In your example, you were claiming that most animals are mammals and someone begun listing fish, birds, crustaceans, insects, arachnids...

Comment: @DaG There's no such thing as a terrible question, since questions are about seeking truth. Questions can be based on misunderstandings, but that still doesn't make them terrible. Trying to pass off a non-answer as an answer is terrible.

Comment: “Terrible” is your adjective, not mine. If you were to ask since when Paris is the capital of Spain, someone might object. Anyway...

Comment: Anyway, I did a purely numerical search on the Zingarelli dictionary, for masculine and feminine nouns ending in “-e”. There are some false positives due to lemmas collating, say, an adjective and a noun derived from it. In any case, for what's worth, it returns 10,487 masculine (*abate* to *zuzzurellone*) and 9,183 feminine (*abbinatrice* to *zucconaggine*) nouns in “-e”. So, a virtual parity.

Comment: Moreover, @CJDennis, this answer is not “terrible” at all, since it – unlike my petty attempt at statistics – does not aim at a quantitative statement, but just at claiming that “-e is not a typically masculine ending”, and it proves it by showing that there are some (even if they were just a few) very important, high-frequency feminine nouns, such as *gente*, *notte*, *pace* and two very feminine ones such as *madre* (mother) and *moglie* (wife). And, moreover, it gives several whole *families* of words (of which those in *-zione* alone, not even *-ione*, represent some 3000 words).

Comment: @DaG I could do the same thing and "prove" that "-a" isn't typically feminine because there are so many masculine exceptions, and vice versa for "-o". Evidence of exceptions is not evidence of a lack of a rule. Your "petty attempt" is actually a much better answer.